# Haproxy dynamic backend matching request header

Tags: header, haproxy

I am trying to find a solution for a problem I have with haproxy. Is something like this possible with haproxy if so can someone help with the right syntax or documentation?

```
Header: key=value
acl custom_header key=value 
use backend value

backend value
server something.value.com
```

The term value should be a var or place holder so I can match particular backend when the request has a particular value for the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the variable in the use backend directive.

Here is a snippet the full answer is here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61931107/6778826

```
frontend fe1
  ...
  use_backend %[req.hdr(key),lower]

backend value
  server something.value.com
```